# iOS side-loaded expo app horizontally flipped

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, right-to-left

I'm using expo in my react native project.

Everything is fine when loaded to either Android or iOS emulators.  However when I side-load it to my actual iOS phone device, everything is flipped.

The header hamburger menu goes to the right even though the drawer still animated from the left.  Text exclamation marks precede the word it's exclaiming.

Even the side drawer content is flipped with the icons on the right and the expand arrows to the left.  Looks very much like it's RTL formatted but I don't remember doing anything of the sort.

---

Loaded on Emulator:

[image]

Loaded onto device:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: This is exactly what is happening to me, were you able to solve it?